# How to access Windows directories inside ubuntu bash

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to access a file, say test.c, from the Windows 10 Desktop on the Ubuntu Bash shell.

Answer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921301/bash-and-ubuntu-subsystem-in-windows-10

I can't comment (less than 50 reputation), and I can't answer it (question was put on hold), and I can't directly message the OP. So I thought I'd share the answer here for maybe a more reputation user can forward to him. Thanks!

Comment: I commented in the other question, adding the link to this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a question being closed isn't an invitation to work around the system to answer it anyway.

Comment: I vote for this to stay. I see this as a way to document this for the public, and not just the other persons question. Anyone googling the question will bump into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On terminal

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/
```

or `cd /mnt/d` or any other drive

Then you can just move the files to the linux home directory

```
mv /mnt/c/Users/path/to/file/ ~/
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question asked was :"Where is new Linux subsystem and Bash are located in Windows 10?"

Through windows explorer this should get you there:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Lxss\home\USERNAME

see this article for more info: http://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/